Access AWS CodeArtifact private package from AWS Device Farm for Appium tests
I am trying to run Appium tests on AWS Device Farm that depend on a private NPM package hosted on AWS CodeArtifact. I'm facing several issues and need guidance on how to resolve them:
Challenges:

I can't install AWS CLI v2 on AWS Device Farm due to the lack of sudo permissions.
Using the AWS CLI installed via pip doesn't support the codeartifact commands.
Packing the dependency and installing it manually triggers an npm login error in AWS

Goal on Device Farm.

To enable my Appium tests to access and install the private NPM package stored in AWS CodeArtifact seamlessly in the AWS Device Farm environment.



version: 0.1
android_test_host: amazon_linux_2
phases:
    install:
        commands:
            - devicefarm-cli use node 20
            - node --version
            - devicefarm-cli use appium 2
            - appium --version
            - export APPIUM_BASE_PATH=/wd/hub
            - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
            - npm install *.tgz

    pre_test:
        commands:
            - |-
                appium --base-path=$APPIUM_BASE_PATH --log-timestamp \
                  --log-no-colors --relaxed-security --default-capabilities \
                  "{\"appium:deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \
                  \"platformName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\", \
                  \"appium:app\": \"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\", \
                  \"appium:udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID\", \
                  \"appium:platformVersion\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\", \
                  \"appium:chromedriverExecutableDir\": \"$DEVICEFARM_CHROMEDRIVER_EXECUTABLE_DIR\", \
                  \"appium:automationName\": \"CustomDriver\"}" \
                  >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appium.log 2>&1 &

            - |-
                appium_initialization_time=0;
                until curl --silent --fail "http://0.0.0.0:4723${APPIUM_BASE_PATH}/status"; do
                  if [[ $appium_initialization_time -gt 30 ]]; then
                    echo "Appium did not start within 30 seconds. Exiting...";
                    exit 1;
                  fi;
                  appium_initialization_time=$((appium_initialization_time + 1));
                  echo "Waiting for Appium to start on port 4723...";
                  sleep 1;
                done;

    test:
        commands:
            - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/node_modules/tests/tests
            - npm install ./private-package-1.0.1.tgz --save
            - npm run remote:tests

    post_test:
        commands:
            - npm run generate-report
            - cp generated-report/index.html $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR

artifacts:
    - $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR



